# Ocean modifier + wave modifier foam

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation, dynamic-paint

I'm having foam issues!

In the example below I have:

1) A boat leaving a trail of foam via dynamic paint

2) Foam on the ocean

3) A wake from a wave modifier

Problem 1

The foam from the ocean doesn't merge with the foam from the boat. They add together and actually end up emitting light! I've tried merging / clamping in the nodes but I don't have the brain power for this. is there a way to limit the maximum value or do you have to do some subtracting?

Problem 2

I want the wave crest generated from the wave modifier to also have foam. I can't even imagine where to begin with this. Such a small thing would add so much to the example

[image]

Thank you

Sean

Comment: Hi, can you provide me .blend file cuz I'm working on a similar project?